# CodeIgniter fail connect to database using IP Address

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I want to connect to database in CodeIgniter using local IP address but it failed,

config/database:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '192.168.1.102',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'webbmkg',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(
    array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => '192.168.1.103',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'webbmkg',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    )
),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

[image: screenshot error]

Error says: "Unable to select specified database"

where my local IP address is 192.168.1.102, but when I change the IP to "localhost" its work.

Actually I want to using IP address from another PC for the failover but its not working, and then I change my default database using IP address its not working too. I think something wrong but I dont know what is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1 :
Give all the privileges to that server.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'192.168.1.103';

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

# service mysql restart
```

Method 2:
**** Create new User and Grant privilege *********

```
mysql> select password('admin@123');
+-------------------------------------------+
| password('admin@123')                       |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *89FA6EAF8B6264AC8D6E84759027252505A3EAEE |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> CREATE USER chirag IDENTIFIED BY password '*89FA6EAF8B6264AC8D6E84759027252505A3EAEE';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'chirag'@'192.168.1.103' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Restart MySql service.

```
# service mysql restart
```

Now you can connect

For listing the users and its privilege.

```
mysql> SELECT host,user,Grant_priv,Super_priv FROM mysql.user;
```

Comment: Thankyou! Its working, yeah the problem is privilages at mysql

Answer (score -1):

Have a try with this:

```
'hostname' => 'http://192.168.1.102',
```

Comment: Why would this change anything